# sum of multidimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I want to perform the sum operation on each subarray using javascript using forEach,map,reduce function, so that ultimately my output should look like:

`sum = [8,13,22]`

but I am not getting the desired output. Please assist where I am going wrong.Thanks.

```
var Data = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":5},{"a":3,"b":4,"c":6},{"a":6,"b":7,"c":9}];
var newArr = [];
Data.forEach(function(item) { 
  item = item.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
  newArr.push([item]);
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: What is the output that you desire?

Answer (score 4):

You could map the summed values, literately.

```js
var data = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 5 }, { a: 3, b: 4, c: 6 }, { a: 6, b: 7, c: 9 }],
    result = data.map(o => Object.values(o).reduce((a, b) => a + b));

console.log(result);
```

---

Just some annotation to the given code:

You can not iterate an object with `reduce`, because that works only for array. To overcome this problem, you need just the values of the object by taking [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and then, you could iterate the values.

Then return the sum without wrapping it in an array.

```js
var Data = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":5},{"a":3,"b":4,"c":6},{"a":6,"b":7,"c":9}];
var newArr = [];
Data.forEach(function(item) { 
    var sum = Object.values(item).reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
    newArr.push(sum);
});

console.log(newArr);
```

A better solution would be the use of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), because you need one value for each element of the array.

```js
var data = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":5},{"a":3,"b":4,"c":6},{"a":6,"b":7,"c":9}];
    newArr = data.map(function(item) { 
        return Object.values(item).reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        });
    });

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your example, Old way

```js
var Data = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":5},{"a":3,"b":4,"c":6},{"a":6,"b":7,"c":9}];
var newArr = [];
Data.forEach(function(object) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        sum += object[property]
    }
 }
  newArr.push(sum);
});
console.log(newArr);
```